# Showing $\pm |2x(\cos(az)+ i y \sin(az))| = \pm |2x| \sqrt{y^2 + (1-y^2)\cos^2(az)}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, arithmetic, roots, absolute-value

I'm trying to figure how why the following equality is true:

$$\pm |2x(\cos(az)+ i y \sin(az))| = \pm |2x| \sqrt{y^2 + (1-y^2)\cos^2(az)}$$

my mathematica === trial says false, I'm not sure how the equality holds. Every other mathematica command I know: ExpToTrig, TrigReduce, TrigExpand, TrigToExp, Simplify, etc don't seem to yield anything fruitful.

Is there any named identity between imaginary expressions (left hand side) and squared inside a square root (right hand side) that I'm not aware of?

Thanks

Comment: $$
 \pm \left| {2x(\cos (az) + iy\sin (az))} \right| =  \pm \left| {2x} \right|\left| {\cos (az) + iy\sin (az)} \right| \\ =  \pm \left| {2x} \right|\sqrt {\cos ^2 (az) + (y\sin (az))^2 }  =  \pm \left| {2x} \right|\sqrt {\cos ^2 (az) + y^2 \sin ^2 (az)}  \\ =  \pm \left| {2x} \right|\sqrt {\cos ^2 (az) + y^2 (1 - \cos ^2 (az))}  =  \pm \left| {2x} \right|\sqrt {y^2  + (1 - y^2 )\cos ^2 (az)} 
$$ provided $a$, $z$ and $y$ are all real.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate on the 2nd equality? moving from the i to the sqrt of squares? that was the essence of my question

Comment: $|a+ib|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ for real $a$ and $b$, by definition. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers

Comment: BAH! of course. If only i had a nickel for every time I forgot the "polar in real/imaginary axes" perspective... please feel free to copy and past to an answer for the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided $a$, $z$ and $y$ are all real,
\begin{align*} &\pm \left| {2x(\cos (az) + iy\sin (az))} \right| =  \pm \left| {2x} \right|\left| {\cos (az) + iy\sin (az)} \right| \\ & =  \pm \left| {2x} \right|\sqrt {\cos ^2 (az) + (y\sin (az))^2 }  =  \pm \left| {2x} \right|\sqrt {\cos ^2 (az) + y^2 \sin ^2 (az)}  \\& =  \pm \left| {2x} \right|\sqrt {\cos ^2 (az) + y^2 (1 - \cos ^2 (az))}  =  \pm \left| {2x} \right|\sqrt {y^2  + (1 - y^2 )\cos ^2 (az)}. \end{align*}